# Closed form of $\int_{x}^{1}\left(1-s\right)^{-1/2}P_{m}^{\left(1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)ds$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $P_{m}^{\left(a,b\right)}\left(s\right)$ the $m$-th [Jacobi polinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials). An old result of Bateman shows that $$
\left(1-x\right)^{\alpha+\mu}\frac{P_{m}^{\left(\alpha+\mu,\beta-\mu\right)}\left(x\right)}{P_{m}^{\left(\alpha+\mu,\beta-\mu\right)}\left(1\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\mu+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha+1\right)\Gamma\left(\mu\right)}\int_{x}^{1}\left(1-y\right)^{\alpha}\frac{P_{m}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(y\right)}{P_{m}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(1\right)}\left(y-x\right)^{\mu-1}dy \tag1
$$
which is a special case of the relation $$
\,_{2}F_{1}\left(a,b;c+\mu;x\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(c+\mu\right)}{\Gamma\left(c\right)\Gamma\left(\mu\right)}\int_{0}^{1}y^{c-1}\left(1-y\right)^{\mu-1}\,_{2}F_{1}\left(a,b;c;xy\right)dy,\quad 0<c<c+\mu,\,x<1 \tag2
$$
and $(2)$ follows integrating term by term the $2F1$. For a work, I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_{x}^{1}\left(1-s\right)^{-1/2}P_{m}^{\left(1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)ds \tag3
$$
and clearly $(3)$ resembles $(1)$ very closely. I tried to use the recurrence relations of $P_{m}^{\left(a,b\right)}\left(s\right)$ to exploit $(1)$ in some way but I falied. So the question is:

> Is it possible to find a closed form in the sense of $(1)$ of $(3)$?

My request seems reasonable given that there are, in the literature, articles that generalize results like $(1)$. For example, see:

1. Chen, S., Shen, J., & Wang, L. L. (2016). Generalized Jacobi functions and their applications to fractional differential equations. Mathematics of Computation, 85(300), 1603-1638.
2. John T. Conway (2021) Indefinite integrals involving Jacobi polynomials
   from integrating factors, Integral Transforms and Special Functions, 32:10, 801-811, DOI:
   10.1080/10652469.2020.1844197
3. Askey, R., & Fitch, J. (1969). Integral representations for Jacobi polynomials and some applications. Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 26(2), 411-437.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

---

Update: from [the formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/JacobiP/20/01/01/) $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}P_{m}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(y\right)=P_{m}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(y\right)\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta+k+m+1}$$ $$+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta+2k+1\right)\left(\beta+k+1\right)_{m-k}}{\left(\alpha+\beta+k+m+1\right)\left(\alpha+\beta+k+1\right)_{m-k}}P_{k}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(y\right)$$ we can in some sense use $(1)$ to evaluate $(3)$, because differentiating $(1)$ with respect $\alpha$ we get $$\int_{x}^{1}\left(1-y\right)^{\alpha-1}P_{m}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(y\right)dy=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{x}^{1}\left(1-y\right)^{\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}P_{m}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(y\right)dy$$ $$+\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\frac{\left(1-x\right)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+m+1}P_{m}^{\left(\alpha+1,\beta-1\right)}\left(x\right) \tag4$$ and the integrals in the RHS of $(4)$ can be evaluated using $(1)$. It is not clear if such expression is more interesting than the sum involving the Chebyshev polynomials obtained by Paul Enta.

Update2: Since we have the connection formula $$P_{n}^{\left(\gamma,\beta\right)}\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(\beta+1\right)_{n}}{\left(\alpha+\beta+2\right)_{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\gamma-\alpha\right)_{n-k}\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta+k+1\right)\left(\alpha+\beta+2k+1\right)\left(\beta+\gamma+n+1\right)_{k}}{\left(n-k\right)!\left(\beta+1\right)_{k}\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta+2\right)\left(\beta+\alpha+n+2\right)_{k}}P_{k}^{\left(\alpha,\beta\right)}\left(x\right)$$ we get, taking $\gamma=1/2,\,\alpha=-1/2,\beta=-1/2$, that $$P_{m}^{\left(1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)=\left[\frac{1}{4^{m}}\binom{2m}{m}\right]\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{P_{k}^{\left(-1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)}{\left[\frac{1}{4^{k}}\binom{2k}{k}\right]}\right)$$ so now we can apply $(1)$, hence now the problem is to understand if $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{P_{k}^{\left(1/2,-3/2\right)}\left(x\right)}{\left[\frac{1}{4^{k}}\binom{2k}{k}\right](2k+1)}$$ has a closed form in terms of the Jacobi polynomials.

Comment: For $m\in\Bbb N$, you can switch $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with [this formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/JacobiPGeneral/16/01/01/0002/)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I know that formula but unfortunately it does not work in this case, since if we use this transformation we continue to get an integral which is not in the form of equation (1).

Answer (score 6):

An equivalent representation of the particular Jacobi polynomial is given [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/JacobiP/03/01/02/0002/)
\begin{equation}
 P_n^{(a,-a)}(z)=\frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)} \frac{(1+z)^{a / 2}}{(1-z)^{a / 2}} P_n^{-a}(z)
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
 P_{m}^{\left(1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)=\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{m!} \frac{(1+s)^{1/4}}{(1-s)^{1/4}} P_n^{-1/2}(s)
\end{equation}
An [explicit form](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP2/02/) of the associated Legendre polynomial is
\begin{equation}
 P_n^\mu(z)=\frac{(1+z)^{\mu / 2}}{(1-z)^{\mu / 2}} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-n)_k(n+1)_k}{\Gamma(k-\mu+1) k !}\left(\frac{1-z}{2}\right)^k
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
 P_{m}^{\left(1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)=\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-m)_k(m+1)_k}{\Gamma(k+3/2) k !}\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)^k
\end{equation}
We have thus
\begin{align}
I&= \int_{x}^{1}\left(1-s\right)^{-1/2}P_{m}^{\left(1/2,-1/2\right)}\left(s\right)ds\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{2^{-k}(-m)_k(m+1)_k}{\Gamma(k+3/2) k !}\int_{x}^{1}(1-s)^{k-1/2}\\
 &=\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-m)_k(m+1)_k}{\Gamma(k+3/2) k !}\frac{2^{1-k}}{2k+1}(1-x)^{k+1/2}
\end{align}
which can be written as
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{4}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{m!}\sqrt{1-x}\,{}_3F_2\left( -m,m+1,1/2;3/2,3/2;\frac{1-x}{2} \right)
\end{equation}

---

Edit

A somewhat nicer expression can be obtained by remarking that
\begin{equation}
 Z\,{}_2F_1\left( -m,m+1,1/2;3/2,3/2;Z^2 \right)=\int_0^Z {}_2F_1\left( -m,m+1;3/2;Z^2 \right)\,dZ
\end{equation}
and [that](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/07/08/0008/)
\begin{equation}
 {}_2F_1\left( -m,m+1;3/2;Z^2 \right)=\frac{(-1)^m}{2m+1}\frac{T_{2m+1}(Z)}{Z}
\end{equation}
where $T_n$ are the Chebyshev plynomials. They verify the recurrence relations
\begin{align}
 \frac{T_{n+1}}x&=-\frac{T_{n-1}}x+2T_n\\
 \int T_n(x)\,dx&=\frac12\left[\frac{T_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}-\frac{T_{n-1}(x)}{n-1}\right]
\end{align}
from which one deduces
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^Z\frac{T_{2m+1}(z)}{z}\,dz=\frac{T_{2m+1}(Z)}{2m+1}+2(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k\frac{T_{2k+1}(Z)}{2k+1}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
 Z\,{}_2F_1\left( -m,m+1,1/2;3/2,3/2;Z^2 \right)=\frac{(-1)^m}{2m+1}\left[\frac{T_{2m+1}(Z)}{2m+1}+2(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k\frac{T_{2k+1}(Z)}{2k+1}\right]
\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{(-1)^m4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{(2m+1)m!}\left[\frac{T_{2m+1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\right)}{2m+1}+2(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k\frac{T_{2k+1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\right)}{2k+1}\right]
\end{equation}
By denoting $x=\cos\theta$ with $0\le\theta\le\pi$, we have $\sqrt{(1-x)/2}=\sin\theta/2$ and $T_{2k+1}=(-1)^k\sin((k+1/2)\theta)$ which gives
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{\Gamma(m+3/2)}{(2m+1)m!}\left[\frac{\sin\left( (m+1/2)\theta \right)}{2m+1}+2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{\sin\left( (k+1/2)\theta \right)}{2k+1}\right]
\end{equation}
which, in turn, can be expressed in terms of a [Lerch-Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function).

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your answer. I know this representation via 3F2, unfortunately it is not known, at least as far as I know, whether it has any representation in terms of combinations of Jacobi polynomials or other known special functions.